# Using where.not in rspec should_receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I am trying to test the parameters to `where.not` by rspec but am unable to find the function that is used to make the call on the Active Record. Can anyone tell me how to mock `where.not` for a class in `rspec`? I have tried the following:

`MyClass.should_receive(:where).not`

`MyClass.should_receive(:where_not)`

`MyClass.should_receive(:not_where)`

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, You can mock it something like this: `expect(Class).to receive(:not).with(id: 101)`